# Rails associations: hash of ids within one column needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have a `User` model and a `Company` model, and I want each user to have a variable number of companies (that they have worked at), that can be pulled by e.g. `current_user.companies`.

The list of companies is provided by me, not the users, and is fixed.

I don't think I want

- to have separate columns in the user model for e.g.
  Company 1, Company 2, Company 3, as some users may have worked for 10
  companies, some only 1...
- to put user ids in the company model, as there are
  multiple users...

How would this work in Rails associations? Do I need to have multiple company IDs in a hash in one column of the User Model to achieve this? If so how do I do this, or is there another way?

Comment: Whats wrong with just a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship?

Comment: thanks - had a feeling it would be straightforward! In the end I used a has_many :through, apparently has_and_belongs_to_many is semi-deprecated now.